# Action to take against UPS

Tags: united-kingdom, property, civil-legal-system, postal-service

I paid for UPS to deliver three parcels but they double charged me for that delivery.

UPS charged me twice for that shipment, and refused to respond to my emails and calls asking them to refund the second charge for that single shipment.

Now UPS are holding my parcels in their warehouse after I got my bank to return the second charge.

What actions can I take against UPS to get them to acknowledge my queries about the double charge, and deliver the parcels I paid to be delivered?

Comment: Hire a lawyer. This site is not for legal advice in specific cases. And I note that you asked a similar question regarding Parcelhero.

Answer (score 2):

You can sue them, notice a [Rule 30(b)(6)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_30) deposition, ask a corporate representative to acknowledge your queries, and ask the court to enter an order requiring UPS to deliver your parcels.